# PHFetchOptions Sort Descriptors not working with [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:..]

Tags: ios, ios8, nssortdescriptor, photokit

Trying to fetch the list of Smart Albums in alphabetical order. I tried sorting on `localizedTitle` and `title` but they generate the same results.

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"localizedTitle" ascending:YES]];

PHFetchResult *smartAlbums = [PHAssetCollection fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumRegular options:options];

for (PHAssetCollection *collection in smartAlbums) {
    NSLog(@"PHAssetCollection: %@", collection.localizedTitle);
}
```

The log shows the results are not coming back in sorted order:

```
2015-09-27 13:34:57.054 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Panoramas
2015-09-27 13:34:57.055 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: All Photos
2015-09-27 13:34:57.055 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Hidden
2015-09-27 13:34:57.055 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Recently Deleted
2015-09-27 13:34:57.055 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Videos
2015-09-27 13:34:57.056 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Favorites
2015-09-27 13:34:57.056 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Slo-mo
2015-09-27 13:34:57.056 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Bursts
2015-09-27 13:34:57.056 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Time-lapse
2015-09-27 13:34:57.056 MyApp[2169:1043459] PHAssetCollection: Recently Added
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340880/can-fetchassetcollectionswithtypes-results-be-sorted-when-fetching-smart-albums